# multiple textures for multiple objects in a single file?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

its been a long time since I tried to make anything for online communities that're driven by personal avatars, and I don't remember it being this difficult to put textures onto a group of objects just so I had a good visual reference to make sure everything lines up as expected.

the problem; I have a set of objects [3] that sit together, a head, a body and legs, when I go to put the texture onto the upper body then switch to the lower body to put the texture on that as well, it just has the texture that the upper body has and I can't work out how to make it display both textures in; 1: an editable state, 2: shows both at the same time

I don't need to be able to 'seamlessly' transition to texturing one or the other, I'd just like to see how they both line up so my models don't have awkward seams. without making my own model from scratch I can't alter where these cut off lines are either. I'm certainly more of an artist than I am a sculpter!

both images are loaded into the 'texture slots' section, it just only appears to handle the last one picked as the texture for all 3 parts of the object, and I can't quite work out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create 3 material slots for your merged object.

In each material slot put a material with the texture for one part of the body.

In edit mode, select a material slot, then select the part of the body that it matches, and click *assign*.

That will assign a different material to each part of the body and you can put the different textures in each part.

Here's an example.  I've already assigned materials to the 'head' and 'body', and have selected the 'leg':

[image: Material properties showing assign button]

Before:

[image: object before assigning the leg material]

After:

[image: Object after assigning the leg material]

For my materials I simply used principled shaders, but you can make each material whatever you want it to be.  Here's a 'body' shader with a musgrave texture:

[image: Material with Musgrave]

and the resulting object:

[image: object in material preview mode]